# Linux NFS - set default user for new files on nfs share

Tags: linux, file-permissions, nfs

I use CentOs as nfs server nad 2 Centos machines as clients. I have some problems with permisions/ownership for new files/directories created from clients on nfs share.

My exports file:

```
/media/nfsshare *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

And my idmap.conf:

```
[Mapping]
Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nobody
```

Finally, fstab on clients:

```
172.18.2.132:/media/nfsshare /shared-disk nfs rw,addr=<ip> 0 0
```

I set /shared-disk permissions to 777 and all clients can create/delete files on mounted share. But:

- I don't want 777 permissions. I rather need 660
- Every file created by clients has owner: '-2 - user #-2' and group
  '-2'. I want to ownership for user who created file - system users
  for each client has the same ids, groups and group ids.

Any tips?

Comment: Should be on serverfault.

Comment: I also added this to serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/589346/linux-nfs-set-default-user-for-new-files-on-nfs-share - anybody?